# Express how do I get the values of headers

Tags: node.js, express

I have this problem, it turns out that I need to access the header data that is enclosed in red (Form Data), however, I can only access the information in orange (Request Headers). I need it to send information from the pdf file that is rendered on the frontend (nextjs). The library I'm using for the pdf is Kendo React, and the "proxyURL" prop is the only thing, in my opinion, that helps me send information to the backend.

[Request Headers and Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEX5P.png)

[Target Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQKv.png)

This is the capture of the req.headers console.log, what I need is out of it, I have been seeing more than 4 hours how to access Form Data. Thanks You Very Much

[Log req.headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8qWU.png)

Attached the server code the proxy is on line 67

```html
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const typeDefs = require('./db/schema');
const resolvers = require('./db/resolvers');
const {
    GraphQLUpload,
    graphqlUploadExpress, // A Koa implementation is also exported.
  } = require('graphql-upload');    

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const conectarDB = require('./config/db');
const { bootstrap: bootstrapGlobalAgent } = require('global-agent');


const cors = require("cors");
require('dotenv').config({path: 'variables.env'});


conectarDB();

bootstrapGlobalAgent();



// const corsOptions = {
//   origin: process.env.PAGINA,
//   optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
//   credentials: true
// }

async function startServer() {
    const server = new ApolloServer({
      typeDefs,
      resolvers,
      cors: {
        credentials:true,
        origin: process.env.PAGINA,
        optionsSuccessStatus:200
      },
      context: ({req}) => {
          // // console.log(req.headers['authorization']);
          const token = req.headers['authorization'] || '';
          // console.log("headers", req.headers);
          if (token) {
              try {
                const usuario = jwt.verify(token.replace('Bearer ', ''), process.env.SECRETA )
                console.log(usuario);
                return {
                  usuario
                }
              } catch (error) {
                console.log("HUBO UN ERROR");
                console.log(error.message);
              }
          }
      }
    });
    
    await server.start();
    
    const app = express();
    // process.env.PAGINA
    try {
        
        app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
        app.use(express.static('public'));
        
        // PROXY
        app.all("/pdf", (req, res, ) => {
            
            console.log("header", req.headers);
            res.send('Data')
        })

        
        
        server.applyMiddleware({ app });
        
        app.use(cors({
          origin: process.env.PAGINA,
          credentials: true,
          optionsSuccessStatus:200
        }))
        
      //   app.use((req, res, next) => {
      //     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      //     res.header(
      //       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      //       "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
      //     );
      //   if (req.method == "OPTIONS") {
      //     const awa = res.status(200).json({})
      //     const data = JSON.stringify(awa);
      //       console.log("data", data);
      //       console.log("uwuw", res.status(200).json({}));
      //     return res.status(200).json({});
      //   }
      
      //   next();
      // });
      // app.use(cors(corsOptions))
        

        
        // await new Promise(r => app.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }, r));
    
        // console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 4000}${server.graphqlPath}`);

        // Arrancar el servidor
        app.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000}, () => {
          console.log(`Servidor corriendo http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 4000}${server.graphqlPath}`);
        })
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error); 
    }
    // This middleware should be added before calling `applyMiddleware`.
    
}

startServer();
```

And the PDFExport component

```html
    <>
      <PDFExport  forceProxy={true} proxyURL={`http://localhost:4000/pdf`} proxyTarget={`Data`} ref={pdfExportComponent} paperSize="A4" fileName="archivo" key="archivo" >
        <div className="body__container" ref={container}>
          <header className="header__container">
            <h1 className="header__title">PRESUPUESTO</h1>
            <div className="header__image"></div>
          </header>

          <div className="section__body">
            <p>Datos del paciente</p>
            <h4>
              Nombre: <label> {nombre}</label>
            </h4>
            <h4>
              Apellido: <label>{apellido} </label>
            </h4>
            <h4>
              Tipo doc: <label>{tipDoc}</label>
            </h4>
            <h4>
              Numero doc: <label>{docNum}</label>
            </h4>
            <h4>
              Fecha:{" "}
              <label>
                {dia}-{String(mes).length === 1 ? `0${mes}` : mes}-{year}
              </label>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div className="table__container">
            <Table size="sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th className="table-cabecera-id">N°</th>
                  <th className="table-cabecera-categoria">Categoría</th>
                  <th className="table-cabecera-tratamiento">Tratamiento</th>
                  <th className="table-cabecera">Cantidad</th>
                  <th className="table-cabecera">C/U</th>
                  <th className="table-cabecera">Descuento</th>
                  <th className="table-cabecera">Costo</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {presupuesto.map((item, index) => (
                  <tr key={item.id}>
                    <td className="table-elementos">{index + 1}</td>
                    <td className="table-elementos" lang="es">
                      {item.categoria}
                    </td>
                    <td className="table-elementos" lang="es">
                      {item.tratamiento}
                    </td>
                    <td className="table-elementos">{item.cantidad}</td>
                    <td className="table-elementos">{item.precio}</td>
                    <td className="table-elementos">{item.descuento}</td>
                    <td className="table-elementos">
                      {item.precio * item.cantidad - item.descuento}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </Table>
          </div>
          <div className="footer">
            <div className="footer__resumen">
              <h4>Subtotal:</h4>
              <label>S/{sumaSub}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="footer__resumen">
              <h4>Descuento:</h4>
              <label>{sumaDesc}%</label>
            </div>
            <div className="footer__resumen">
              <h4>Total: </h4>
              <label>S/{montoTotal}</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="body__doctor">
            <h4>Atentamente, Dr. {doctor.nombre} {doctor.apellido}.</h4>
          </div>

          <div className="footer__contacto">
            <div className="footer__contacto-datos">
              <h4 className="datos__title">
                ODONTO<label>TRENDS</label>
              </h4>
              <h4>92034933838</h4>
              <h4>
                Direccion:{" "}
                <p className="datos__direccion">
                  Av. Angelica Gamarra 561 Urb El Trebal - Los Olivos LIMA
                </p>
              </h4>
              <h4>
                Telefono: <p>920411227</p>
              </h4>
            </div>

            <div className="footer__contacto-sociales">
              <h4 className="footer__contacto-title">Redes sociales</h4>
              <div className="sociales__container">
                <h4>Odontotrends</h4>
                <div className="sociales-facebook"></div>
              </div>

              <div className="sociales__container">
                <h4>odonto_trends</h4>
                <div className="sociales-instagram"></div>
              </div>

              <div className="sociales__container">
                <h4>977 182 001</h4>
                <div className="sociales-whatsapp"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </PDFExport>
      </>
```

Comment: So form values are not usually in headers and your log of the headers seems to show that.  If you show your actual relevant code (client and server), then we can advise  on how to get at the data you want.

Comment: FYI, if this is a form post and you're using Express, then you would install the appropriate middleware - probably`app.use(express.urlencoded())`.  Then your form values would be in `req.body`.

Comment: Now that you've added some code, where is the request handler you're trying to read form data from?

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/pdfprocessing/api/PDFExportProps/#toc-proxytarget
In the documentation it mentions that with the proxyURL prop it sends the PDF through a post request in base64 and indeed, but it does not attach me in the "Content-Disposition" header, it sends it separately

Comment: A POST request puts the data in the request body, not as a header.  Your request handler that is handling that POST request will need to read and parse the body of the request.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you very much!!! And all of you. I can finally get the data!

Answer (score 0):

A POST request puts the data in the request body, not as a header. Your request handler that is handling that POST request will need to read and parse the body of the request.

If this is a form post and you're using Express, then you would install the appropriate middleware - probably `app.use(express.urlencoded())`. Then your form values would be in `req.body`.

If the data is an uploaded file, then you may need additional middleware to parse the mime body such as [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).